# Inductive effect in cyclic compounds vs open-chained compounds

Tags: organic-chemistry, stability, carbocation

[image]

Consider the two carbocations. Which one is more stable? I think it should be the open-chained one as it has 2 more H atoms than the cyclic one, so polarity will be greater; but I suspect that there might be some other factors at play  here due to the ring that I might have missed.